# Is there any function that never gives an answer other than 0/0 when applying L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Someone asked this question in my calculus class and the teacher said that he would get back to the student on that one. I never heard back, so was hoping someone here knew the answer?

**EDIT**
Sorry guys, I think I worded the question wrong, so I attempted to rewrite it...

Comment: I think the question is harder to understand now. Do you mean a function for which you can keep applying the rule repeatedly as many time as you want?

Comment: @PratyushSarkar YES! Thank you! A function for which you can keep applying the rule repeatedly as many times as you want - and never get an answer other than 0/0.

Comment: Then the appropriate answers are given by Sami and Maesumi. But keep in mind that even though you keep getting $0/0$, there is an actual value to the limit ... you just have to take a different approach than L'Hopital.

Comment: Related: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{x\over\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean by continuous, but consider $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} {{e^{-x}}\over{e^{-2x}}}$. Under the brute-force application of  LHopital's it remains at $0/0$.

Comment: Of course this even holds with $\frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}}$ :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{1/x}}{e^{-1/x^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that just means that the first two derivatives of both the numerator on denominator go to zero continuously. An example, albeit not a very interesting one, is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^4}{x^4}$.

Comment: After four applications of l'Hôpital, this example turns into a definite form.

Comment: I provided the answer before the clarification. Others have now given better examples.